# custom made Magento website to responsive website

Tags: web

I have created a custom website using the Magento platform (No pre-defined theme is used). This is a completely created from the scratch. Now after developing the website, some slider in homepage is not displaying properly in the mobile version in addition to other pages. Can you guys help me out?. I am fine to buy an extension or do any other minor changes, so that I can go-live with my website immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out themes there in magento commerce?

Also tryout inspect element from browser to rule out syntactic errors

All the Best

KK

Comment: Thanks KK, But I have already created a website, so we cannot use a theme in magento.